# Will starting an async process within a Rails begin-end block cause an issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am looking to start an async worker task within a begin-end block in rails. Ex:

```
begin
 a = 1
 b = a + 2
 Workers::SideKiqAsynTask.new().process
end
```

I am having trouble understanding if the begin will wait for the Workers task which is a Sidekiq async process to complete.

Comment: no it won't. but you should use activejob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version is a Sidekiq job that's run asynchronously will not hold up the `begin...end`. That said, it looks like you're maybe trying to do something with a deeper down Sidekiq class.

The longer explanation:

So if you're trying to kick of a single run of a single task you usually create a new class that includes the `Sidekiq::Worker` module. Then you define a method called `perform` that does the work you want to do asynchronously. Then you call `perform_async` on your worker. It looks something like this:

```
# in app/workers
class MyCoolWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(numbers)
    crunch_numbers_for_a_long_time(numbers)
  end
end

# wherever you want to kick off a task
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
MyCoolWorker.perform_async(numbers)
```

You can also schedule a task for a specific time

```
MyCoolWorker.perform_in(1.hour)
```

You will need to have Redis installed and run Sideqik with `bundle exec sidekiq`

`perform_async` and `perform_in` will just tell sidekiq "Hey please do this for me when you can / at the time I tell you" It's very quick and then done. The actually work gets done by Sidekiq in a different Ruby process.

Here's a good place for help in Sidekiq's documentation:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started

There's even a presentation :)